# How to solve subcaption package compatibility issue when using babel package with arabic option?

Tags: babel, subcaption, incompatibility, arabic

I am trying to include some Arabic text but I am getting the following error:

```
! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.
```

Here is a MWE which produces the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
 اللغة العربية
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you make do with the capabilities of the `subfig` package, in lieu of the `subcaption` package?

Comment: I tried that, but it resulted in many errors.

Comment: And what would some of those errors be? (I'm assuming that you adjusted the subfigure-related instructions to conform to the syntax rules of the `subfig` package.)

Comment: I got a lot of "Missing number, treated as zero" , "illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)", and "\begin{figure} ended by \end{subfigure}". I have not made any changes in the instructions. I will check that.

Comment: The syntax requirements for the two packages are definitely not the same.

Comment: I'll naively ask: did you try loading `babel` before `subcaption`?

Answer (score 2):

I opened an issue at https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/5 but I'm having a hard time adapting the `caption`/`subcaption` package to the `arabic` babel package. Since I don't know the Arabic language I can only compare the outcome without and with (sub)caption package, and if they are not the same I can assume I've done something wrong.

But the outcome of the `arabic` babel package looks inconsistent to me:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{اللغة العربية}
\caption{اللغة العربية اللغة العربية اللغة العربية اللغة العربية اللغة العربية اللغة العربية}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: babel-arabic captions]

Which ones of the two captions have the correct caption label formatting? Should it be on the left or on the right of the caption text? And how about the caption label itself? Should it read "Figure 1.0" (like in the long caption) or "1.0 Figure" (like in the short one)?

So I need assistance here from a person who is familiar with typography of Arabic language. If you want to help me and make an adaption of the caption/subcaption package to Arabic happen, please contact me. You'll find my e-mail address in the README of the caption package bundle: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/README

Thanks.

Addendum 2018-05-29: Is this correct a correct caption layout? [image]

Comment: Solution 2 did not work for me

Comment: @Salah I'm currently working on solving this issue in the caption (and subcaption) package, so please hold the line...

Comment: @Salah Could you please help me? (See my edited answer above.)

Comment: Since no-one is willing to clarify what the expected outcome should be, I will not fix it for version 3.3. (Hopefully someone will help fixing this for version 3.4, otherwise I will just close the issue unfixed.)

Comment: I don't know why but I did not receive a notification of your previous comment. So here I am glad to clarify. The first caption is the correct one. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Salah Thanks for your help! I just appended a new picture to my answer above, could you please take a look at it? That would be very kind. Is this how long captions should look like? If not, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Both captions are correct in this picture. The length is fine as well.

Comment: @Salah Thanks for looking at this. I will make a version of the caption/subcaption package which produces this output on the very next week-end (and will drop a note here).

Comment: Thanks Axel for you contribution. I look forward to this version.

Comment: @Salah I just build a new version. Could you please download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/babel/arabic/tex/caption.sty and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/babel/arabic/tex/caption3.sty and try out if everything is ok using this version? (Captions, sub-captions, list of figure/table, `\nameref` etc.)

Comment: @Salah Addendum: Please load the new caption package *after* the arabtex and babel packages.

Comment: @Salah Unfortunately I had to delete my Github account yesterday. (Will look for an alternative on week-end...) If you don't have managed to get the files yet, please send me an e-mail.

Comment: @Salah The package files can now be found at https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/tree/babel/arabic/tex

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am sorry that I was not very reactive. I am currently dealing with the reviews of a paper that I have to submit in few days.

Comment: @Salah No problem, take your time.