# Why does LaTeX step the footnote counter twice in a two-line caption?

Tags: floats, captions

In the following code there are three figures, each has a caption with a footnote. I would expect them to be numbered continuously from 1 to 3. But in reality (tested with TL 17 and TL 18) the footnote counter is incremented twice when the caption has two lines (does not scale, i.e. with a third line it's still stepped twice).

[image: problem]

[image: end of page]

*Question:* What's the reason for this double-stepping?

*Side note:* I'm not looking for a solution, because the problem can easily be fixed by including the `caption` package. I'm interested in an explanation why a second line in the caption might cause a counter mess.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test1\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Footnote 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test2 -- This is a very long caption which should still get a foonote numbered with 2\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Footnote 2}
\begin{figure}[htbp] % [htbp] only added for staying on top]
\caption{Test3\protect\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Footnote 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Singlelinecheck would be my guess.

Comment: see the definition of `\@makecaption` in `article.cls` or with `\meaning\@makecaption`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It steps it because the caption is typeset twice. Firstly it is set in an `\sbox` and measured, and if that one-line setting would fit the box is centred, however if that line would be too long, the whole caption is set again in a `\parbox` so that it is set as a justified paragraph.

It would be possible to save/restore the counters as for example `tabularx` or `amsmath` do when doing similar trial settings, but as the default float handling doesn't support footnotes anyway and things were *very* short of space for extra save/restore code when this was designed in the 1980's, it doesn't, so you would need to use `\footnotemark[]` with the current number and then use `\footnotetext[]` outside the caption.

Note the solution of turning off the single line check works fine in this example as you get the same `\parbox` setting, and by skipping the check you get the right number, but if you do that as a global document change then

```
\caption{a very long caption}
```

would get a different setting as a justified (so flush left as it is one line) paragraph, rather than being centred.

Comment: Footnotes are not the only problem here, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428788/acronym-subcaption-problems-with-acronyms-in-captions. The caption package tries to offer a concept for avoiding these problems in general (and simply including the caption package helps, and you don't need to switch off the single-line-check for that), but since this is not an official concept offered by LaTeX itself, no other package (I'm aware of) takes advantage of this concept.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Do you know what KOMA does? It doesn't show this problem either.

Comment: @TeXnician KOMA-Script has the following code lines inside `\@@makecaption` for the single-line-check: `\def\stepcounter##1{\advance\value{##1}\@ne}\let\refstepcounter\stepcounter`. This takes care that counters incremented with `refstepcounter` (like the footnote counter) are not incremented twice when used in captions.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt with the post 2015 latex update policy we _could_ do something similar in the base format but a lot of packages (some with your name on:-) patch in to that code, so there is always a danger that improving the code does more harm than good. Standard dilemma of maintaining latex:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Somehow one has to draw a line. Many (unpublished) document classes patch internal code of the endfloat package. So maintaining the endfloat package means for me: Do not change a single line since it could break compatiblity!? I don't subscribe that pov. Make a list of "good" packages which you would like to continue to support. If these packages can handle the change (or are being maintained so they can be adapted), simply do it. Another idea: Keep compatibility by changing nothing to LaTeX2e. Publish LaTeX2f instead, with hyperref, some of oberdiek and some of KOMA inside.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Regarding the change in `\@makecaption`: Please offer `\@prepareslc` (like `\caption@prepareslc`) so other packages can re-define stuff for preparation of the single-line-check, too. (`\g@addto@macro\@prepareslc{...}`)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I'll look in to it If I have anything I'll open a gh issue and ping you before it goes live (won't be this weekend:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sounds good!