# Figure captions are not expanding long glossary acronyms—what controls this behavior?

Tags: floats, acronyms

I have encountered (what I imagine is) a bug where acronyms of different lengths are not handled consistently in figure captions. Short acronyms are expanded on first use (as expected), but  long acronyms are never expanded. Here is a MWE showing the issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{vsa}{VSA}{Very Short Acronym}
\newacronym{vla}{VLA}{Very Looooooooooooong Acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{This is a caption with a \gls{vsa}.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{This is a caption with a \gls{vla}.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
   \caption{This is another caption with a \gls{vsa}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE-caption-acronym-anomaly]

This behavior is very similar to what's described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428788/acronym-subcaption-problems-with-acronyms-in-captions), and [the selected answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431633/227722) there suggests that single-line figure captions are evaluated once while multi-line figure captions are evaluated twice. Presumably the expanded rendering of the acronym gets used in the first evaluation, while the condensed rendering is used (and displayed) in the second evaluation. This conclusion makes sense given the unusual page formatting.

That solution indicates a patch for the caption package may have been in the works (although the linked GitHub repo is defunct, and I didn't find a related issue on the new corresponding [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption)). Since I did not use the caption package in the MWE, I'm skeptical that a patch there would fix this anyway, unless somehow the caption package is being called under the hood. I just updated TeX Live to 2020 (along with updates to all of the packages) hoping that a patch may have made it through there, but no luck.

Any known solutions to this? Or, perhaps a better question, where would one go looking for the code that might need to be updated?

Comment: When I add `\usepackage{caption}` the problem seems to go away, so I assume there is a fix included in the `caption` package for it.

Furthermore https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.4926.1527618512.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org claims the problem was fixed on 2018-05-27.

Comment: Ooof, definitely should've tested that out—it works for me too. Thanks! (I'd say that probably merits a correct answer if you want to add it as a solution